# Inserting MongoDB long values with Java

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm attempting to insert a date, as a long value, into MongoDB in Java. When I attempt to insert one, it appears as NumberLong("12345"), which appears to be a string within NumberLong(). Unless this is a misunderstanding of mine.

This is my line of code--where parserSDF is a Java Date object:

```
        BasicDBObject dbDate = new BasicDBObject("dateCreated",parserSDF.getTime());
```

This is how the field appears by default:

```
  ...  "dateCreated" : NumberLong(0) ...
```

But this is how it changes when attempting to write a long:

```
"dateCreated" : NumberLong("1426632572797")
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: That's correct - it's shell syntax. A plain number like `{ "dateCreated" : 12345 }` means a double type.